# Adding custom property in Identity membership

Tags: asp.net-identity

I was following an [MSDN tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) on how to add a property to the existing `ApplicationUser` class. I named it AccountCode and by using Add-Migration AccountCode and then Update-Database I see that it makes its way in to my database.

However, I'm trying to update the property so that it is non nullable and is an IdentityColumn. In my Migration file for Account code I modified the code within the Up method to this:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", 
                  "AccountCode", c => c.Int(identity: true, nullable: false));
    }
```

When I run `Update-Database` it says there is no detected changes to my migrations.

I've googled a dozen times and can't find anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I understand what you did you added the column AccountCode and after the fact you are trying to alter the same column to be non-nullable and an identity column. Is that correct?  If that is the case you would not add the column, you would alter it. And you would alter the existing column that was the identity.

Comment: @KevinJunghans That's correct. Are you saying I should change my code from `AddColumn` to `AlterColumn`?

Comment: Have you tried using [Key] attribute to the AccountCode in your ApplicationUser? Note, IdentityUser already has one key, so make your decision right..

Comment: It should end up being an alter but I would not write the code manually. I would modify the schema using attributes as jd4u suggested or use the Fluent API. Then use code migration in the package manager console to create a new migration and generate the code for you.